# AsyncTask return value only after using get() method

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I've created activity, which should return array of GeoPoint after user clicked the button. Code which perform http request and parse answer is extracted to AsyncTask. In the `onPostExecute()` method I've assigned `overlayList` with value returned by `doInBackground()` method, but it didn't work and

```
overlayList.size()
```

thows an NullPointerException. Here is my original code:

```java
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

Button bt;
TextView tv1;
List<GeoPoint> overlayList;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String query = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=bla-bla&destination=bla-bla&sensor=false";

            Request mat =  new Request();
            mat.execute(query);

            if (overlayList.size() > 0){
                tv1.setText("List is OK!");
            }

        }
    });
}

private class Request extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<GeoPoint>> {

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<GeoPoint> doInBackground(String... params) {
        return parse(connect(params[0]));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<GeoPoint> geoPoints) {
        super.onPostExecute(geoPoints);
        overlayList = geoPoints;
    }

    public JSONObject connect(String url) {
        ...    
    }

    public ArrayList<GeoPoint> parse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
        ...
    }

}
```

But if I'll modify my `OnClickListener` in such way:

```java
HttpRequest mat =  new HttpRequest();
mat.execute(query);

try {
    overlayList = mat.get();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

all going ok and `overlayList.size()` return size of the list. So, my question - why is `onPostExecute()` method do not initialize my list?

Comment: overlayList.add (geoPoints);

Comment: do not call `super.onPostExecute(geoPoints);`.

Comment: can u post your parse(connect(...)) code

Comment: `async` means its asynchronous. it means it is executed in another thread, and it means the next line statement cannot be based on the idea that the task has been executed.

Comment: @WebnetMobile : There's no problem with calling `super.onPostExecute(...)`, the default implementation does nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `AsyncTask` does exactly what it's name suggests - the `doInBackground(...)` method runs asynchronously on a separate thread while the code in `onCreate(...)` continues to run.

In your code here...

```
mat.execute(query);

if (overlayList.size() > 0){
    tv1.setText("List is OK!");
}
```

...the `if` condition is checked *immediately* after you call `mat.execute(query)`. In other words, your `AsyncTask` hasn't had a chance to execute it's `doInBackground(...)` method.

Move this code...

```
if (overlayList.size() > 0){
    tv1.setText("List is OK!");
}
```

...into the `onPostExecute(...)` method of your `AsyncTask`.

EDIT: As triggs points out in the comment below, calling the `get()` method of `AsyncTask` will block the main thread and wait for the result to be returned. This effectively makes using an `AsyncTask` become a synchronous operation in which case there's no point in using an `AsyncTask`.

The only reason I can think of to use the `get()` method would be from a thread other than the main (UI) thread although I can't think of many reasons to do that.

Comment: In addition to the above the reason the second way you posted works is because calling the `get()` method on an AsyncTask causes it to block the main thread until the task is finished.