# ProcessDialog is not appearing properly?

Tags: android

This is my function that is in LoginActivity.java.So onclick of button i am calling this function.

```
public  void postHttpRequest(String userId,String pass,TextView error){
        RequestClient reqClient = new RequestClient(LoginActivity.this);
        String AppResponse = null;
        try {
            url = "myurl";
            Log.d("URL", url);
            AppResponse = reqClient.execute().get();
            String status = ValidateLoginStatus.checkLoginStatus(AppResponse);
            Log.d("Status recived", status);

            if(status.equals("200")){
                saveInformation(userId,pass);
                startingActivity(HOST_URL);
            }else{
                error.setText("Incorrect UserName or Password");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Exception Occured", "Exception is "+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

From this function i am calling a AsynkTask for Http Communication.So onclick of button when i am geeting the response then my processDialog in opening just for one sec.I want as i click the buttoon my processDialog should get open utill i got the response

```
public class RequestClient extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    Context context;

    public RequestClient(Context c) {
        context = c;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        pDialog.setMessage("Authenticating user...");
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... aurl){
    String responseString="";
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient=new DefaultHttpClient();
    try {
         HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  
         HttpGet get = new HttpGet(LoginActivity.url);
         HttpResponse responseGet = client.execute(get);  
         HttpEntity resEntityGet = responseGet.getEntity();  
         if (resEntityGet != null) {  
             responseString = EntityUtils.toString(resEntityGet);
             Log.i("GET RESPONSE", responseString);
         }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC_ERROR", "Error is "+e.toString());
    }
    Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC_ERROR", responseString);
     httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
     return responseString;

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
         super.onPostExecute(response); 
            if(pDialog!=null) 
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

So please suggest me what changes i  have to make so that processDialog should display properly in the center of the device

Comment: Perhaps you do close the dialog in onPostExecute. Put a breakpoint in there and see.

Comment: Isn't your progress showing now at all?

Comment: After getting the response the dialog in opening for just 1 sec

Comment: @GauravPandey do you see the log messages in `doInBackground`?

Comment: @GauravPandey is your asynctask an inner class of your activity class or is it a seperate file.

Comment: Yes @Raghunandan there is no error in that log.It is in the separate file

Comment: @GauravPandey did you try the below does it work now?

Comment: Same problem i am facing @Raghunandan

Comment: @GauravPandey edit your question and shows us the update. It should work fine if you do it right. can't see any reason why it won't work

Comment: @GauravPandey you are not passing the url to `doInBackground()`. Check your log cat if you see any log messages looged in `doInBackground()`. `Log.i("GET RESPONSE", responseString);`.

Comment: @Raghunandan it's showing a lot of compile time errors .When i am trying to use u r code.

Comment: @GauravPandey update you code

Comment: @GauravPandey works now been a day no update?

Comment: @Raghunandan it's working fine now thanks alot  for u help and co-operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[AsyncTask return value only after using get() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15952999/asynctask-return-value-only-after-using-get-method)

Drawing from the above link

Calling the `get()` method of `AsyncTask` will block the main thread and wait for the result to be returned. This effectively makes using an AsyncTask become a synchronous operation in which case there's no point in using an AsyncTask.

The only reason I can think of to use the `get()` method would be from a thread other than the main (UI) thread although I can't think of many reasons to do that.

On Button click

```
       RequestClient reqClient = new RequestClient(LoginActivity.this,new TheInterface() {
             @Override
             public void theMethod(String result) {
                 Log.i("Result  =",result); 
            }  
        });
       reqClient.execute(url); // no get(). pass url to doInBackground()
```

In your activity class

```
    public interface TheInterface {  
    public void theMethod(String result);

       }
     }
```

AsyncTask

```
public class RequestClient extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    Context context;
    TheInterface listener; 
    public RequestClient(Context c,TheInterface listen) {
        context = c;
        listener = listen;   
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        pDialog.setMessage("Authenticating user...");
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... aurl){
    String responseString="";
     HttpClient client; 
    try {
         HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  
         HttpGet get = new HttpGet(aurl[0]); // url 
         HttpResponse responseGet = client.execute(get);  
         HttpEntity resEntityGet = responseGet.getEntity();  
         if (resEntityGet != null) {  
             responseString = EntityUtils.toString(resEntityGet);
             Log.i("GET RESPONSE", responseString);
         }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC_ERROR", "Error is "+e.toString());
    }
    Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC_ERROR", responseString);
     client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
     return responseString;

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
         super.onPostExecute(response); 
              pDialog.dismiss();
              if (listener != null) 
              {
                listener.theMethod(result);
              }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

//add style in your progressbialog

```
 protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        pDialog.setMessage("Authenticating user..."); 

if (pDialog != null && !pDialog.isShowing()) {
                        pDialog.show();
                    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your button code is not correct, because it's async, but you are trying to use it as standart sync code.

Try to move this code into onPostExecute:

```
String status = ValidateLoginStatus.checkLoginStatus(response);
            Log.d("Status recived", status);

            if(status.equals("200")){
                saveInformation(userId,pass);
                startingActivity(HOST_URL);
            }else{
                error.setText("Incorrect UserName or Password");
            }
```

and make this button click code:

```
public  void postHttpRequest(String userId,String pass,TextView error){
        RequestClient reqClient = new RequestClient(LoginActivity.this);
        String AppResponse = null;
        try {
            url = "myurl";
            Log.d("URL", url);
            reqClient.execute();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Exception Occured", "Exception is "+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```