# Async Task Issue (Wait for Result)

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a async task running and in it i will get result from a connected device. Async task should terminate and execute onPostExcute AFTER receiving the result. Is there a way to execute such a flow of waiting till there is a reply ? Thanks

```
private void getData(){
    final Context con = this.getActivity();
    String tmp;
    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        private ProgressDialog pd;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            pd = new ProgressDialog(con);
            pd.setTitle("Scanning...");
            pd.setMessage("Please wait.");
            pd.setCancelable(false);
            pd.setIndeterminate(true);
            pd.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            try {
                tmp = Control.getReply();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            pd.dismiss();
            startTestModeControl(tmp);
        }
    };
    task.execute((Void[])null);
}
```

Comment: It's the default behavior.. It will hang until Control.getReply() is done, unless that's also an async method which works with listeners.

Comment: I don't know which device you're connected to and if you have a program running on it that you can modify, anyway I would do that using streams. You just send something and wait for the reply, it's a blocking call the AsyncTask cannot move on until it gets the reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for something lika a Listener / Observer. So have a look at the Observerpattern. To do that asynchroniously make the object that processes data in a own AsyncTask or Thread and use the onPostExecute() to inform the Listener that the result is ready.

If you are looking for a way to dispatch a result and Listener / Observer pattern is not what you are looking for, you can use Androids Hander class.

Comment: Hi sockeqwe , I think the Listener/Observer is what i am looking for . I think i will implement it with a listener interface. Is there a way i can get the async task to execute onPostExecute when i a notify through my interface ?

Comment: @sean check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17398837/processdialog-is-not-appearing-properly if it helps.