# Calling the second activity from AsyncTask of the first in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-asynctask, show

I've 2 layouts: MainActivity.xml, MenuActivity.xml.
I want to load the MenuActivity from AsyncTask of the 1-st.
Here's the UPDATED code:

```
class InternetCheck extends AsyncTask<Activity, Void, Boolean> {
    public Activity act=new Activity();


    protected Boolean doInBackground(Activity... activities) {

        boolean status=false;

        act=activities[0];
        String rurl=act.getString(R.string.url_test);


        try 

        {

        URL url = new URL(rurl);

            HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
            urlc.setConnectTimeout(1000 * 20); // mTimeout is in seconds
                    urlc.connect();
            if (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                status=true;
            }

        }
            catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                status=false;
            } 

            catch (IOException e) {
                status=false; 
            }

        return status;

    }


    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {


        if (result==false) {
            MainActivity mActivity = (MainActivity) act;
            mActivity.ShowNoConnectionButton();
        }
        else
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(act, MenuActivity.class);
            act.startActivity(intent);
            //setContentView(R.layout.menu_activity);

        };


    }


}
```

If result is false we show button from UI class, and if it's true, we must load the second activity. For startActivity(intent) I get error: the method is undefined for type InternetCheck.
Also is it all right with Intent parameters and calling UI method ShowNoConnectionButton from AsyncTask? It's rather difficult to understand what we must put in Intent parameters and how to get these.

BUT IT STOPS THE APP WITH ERROR.

The second screen class:

```
public class MenuActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu_activity);

    }


}
```

Comment: use `act.startActivity(intent)`. also your parameter must be `boolean result`. and also you miss `super.onPostExecute(result)`.

Comment: Is the `AsyncTask` an inner class of `MainActivity`?

Comment: @Squonk i guess not coz op says  "For startActivity(intent) I get error: the method is undefined for type InternetCheck"

Comment: One question?.Is this class for pinging a server or checking if you have a connection?

Comment: its better to have asynctask as a inner class of your activity class. or do as suggested here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17398837/processdialog-is-not-appearing-properly.

Comment: @JoelBodega i too suspect the same.

Comment: This is for connecting to a given server

Comment: I'd like to have the simplest solution possible. For understand how it works firstly. Going to the other screen - is it so hard?

Comment: @user2543953 Buddy, people are trying to determine here whether you are actually approaching the problem the correct way. You are connecting to a server to check a response code. It'a ok if you are pinging the server. If this is to check if you have A internet access, it's a wrong approach altogether.

Comment: No, it's checking for this server namely. The connection I check in the other place. But the problem now is to go to the other screen depending on result

Comment: So how can I pass the Activity to doInBackground as parameter and use it, the same also in onPostExecute?

Comment: @user2543953 its better to make your asynctask an inner class of your activity class. and you don't pass activity to `doInbackground`

Comment: Do you mean "extends" keyword or else? For now it's not simple for me, working with Java recently

Comment: @user2543953 what is that your asynctask does exactly? Inner class means within the scope of your activity class.

Comment: Asynctask check whether the given web-server gives 200 HTTP response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your AsyncTask class' constructor, you should accept the context (instance of activity starting the async task) as parameter and save it in member variable, and later use it in onPostExecute as context.startActivity().

This means that you should define a constructor for AsyncTask, and not use default no-argument constructor.

UPDATE: after seeing your full code, I suggest below:

You should not construct activities on your own.

```
class InternetCheck extends AsyncTask<Activity, Void, Boolean> {

    private MainActivity act;

    public InternetCheck(Activity activity) {
        this.act = (MainActivity)activity;
    }
...


protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {


        if (result==false) {
            act.ShowNoConnectionButton();
        }
        else
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(act, MenuActivity.class);
            act.startActivity(intent);
        };

    }
...
}
```

Comment: op seems to have activity context  `MainActivity mActivity = (MainActivity) act`.

Comment: @Raghunandan it also appears that this is a nested class, too. Hence the `startActivity(intent)`

Comment: @JoelBodega in that case op won't get this " For startActivity(intent) I get error: the method is undefined for type InternetCheck". startActivity is a method of activity class and it looks like asynctask in a different file.

Comment: Unfortunately, when using this new code the app STOPS again. But it's more clear, thanks. What can it be else, I don't know. Maybe something in new screen class logic...

Comment: Probably missing in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Look in the logcat, there is always something there...probably an exception trace

Comment: Added to manifest missing activity, now seems to be normally, yet to test. Thanks, guys!

Comment: Maybe you can provide the code sample for my task which is better or clarificate what's not good or what would be better in your way?