# Passing String to AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

So I have a string (that is an link to a page) and I need to pass it to a AsyncTask. Here's my code:

```
url = "http://www.railpnrapi.com/";
url = url.concat(numPNR);
new MyTask().execute(url);
```

and here's my AsyncTask:

```
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
String page = new Communicator().executeHttpGet(url);    
return page;
}
```

I know my implementation is wrong ! How do I correct it to get a valid output as a string?

Comment: why do you need another class you can have just the method and pass the string as `String page = executeHttpGet(params[0])`. check your previous question

Comment: @Raghunandan I just defined the class in my main activity as you said. isn't it a good OOP practice?

Comment: post your code activity code here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need get string via index on async task like below code:

```
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
String page = new Communicator().executeHttpGet(params[0]);    
return page;
}
```

you can get the return string from asynctask like below code:

```
String page = new MyTask().execute(url).get();
```

Comment: I need to pass just one string, so is it ok to define AsyncTask<String, Void, String> or should I change them to void? I assume the first parameter is passed to the doInBackground function. Is It so?

Comment: second parameter void assumes the onprogressupdate() method and antoher string from doinbackground() returned to postexecute() method on your asynctask class override methods!

Comment: So is it mandatory to write a post execute method? How can I store the returned string from doInbackground in the main activity? String page = new MyTask().execute(url).toString(); is OK?

Comment: @Anurupa_Dey if your asynctask is a inner class of your activity class you can declare a string variable as a class member and use the same.

Comment: @StackOverflowUser Calling the `get()` method of AsyncTask will block the main thread and wait for the result to be returned. This effectively makes using an AsyncTask become a synchronous operation in which case there's no point in using an AsyncTask.

Comment: @Anurupa_Dey you don't need to call `get`.

Comment: @Raghunandan that's time you need create method on activity class and it's call with string arguments from doinbackground() on async task!

Comment: @StackOverflowUser i din't get your comment. may be you can post some code.

Comment: @StackOverflowUser your previous comment is unclear. you suggested to use `get`. So can you show how to use the same?

Comment: @Raghunandan yes use get method wait for asyntask complete to response!

Comment: @StackOverflowUser `get` method of AsyncTask will block the main thread and wait for the result to be returned. SO i would not recommend this.

Comment: @Raghunandan you need to indicate progress dialog while during asynctask execution before start and dismiss progress dialog after responsed!

Comment: @StackOverflowUser further commenting will lead to discussion. i will stop it here. but i suggest you read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15952999/asynctask-return-value-only-after-using-get-method

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
String page = new Communicator().executeHttpGet(url);
```

to

```
String page = new Communicator().executeHttpGet(params[0]);
```

You could also take the String in in the constructor for your AsyncTask and store it in the instance.

The `...` after a parameter mean that it is a vararg, which means it take multiple parameters of that type and puts them into an array for you. You need to treat it like an array within your method.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
String page = new Communicator().executeHttpGet(params[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change your code like this:

```
 class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

 @Override
 protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
 String page = new Communicator().executeHttpGet(params[0]);    
 return page;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify your class like this.

```
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

String url;

MyTask(String paramUrl)
{
this.url = paramUrl;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
String page = new Communicator().executeHttpGet(url);    
return page;
}
```

And use it like below;

```
new MyTask(url).execute();
```